# Nginx: proxy_bind v/s proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, httpserver, proxypass

I am sorry in advance if its a dumb question but being new to Nginx, I came across the 2 directives inside server context:

> proxy_bind

and

> proxy_pass.

I know that if I need to send different request from the client to different browsers, I will need to define **proxy_pass** directive defining the domain name and port.

But then why is proxy_bind needed. 
Any help is welcome.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: To bind outgoing network if your server have several uplinks. You don't need it, I guess

Answer (score 0):

In Nginx, the proxy_bind directive is used to specify the local IP address and/or port that Nginx should bind to when making a proxy request to a backend server. This is useful in situations where you have multiple network interfaces or IP addresses on your Nginx server, and you want to specify which one should be used for outbound connections.

For example, let's say you have an Nginx server with two network interfaces: eth0 and eth1. You want Nginx to use the IP address assigned to eth1 when making requests to a backend server using the proxy_pass directive. In this case, you would use the proxy_bind directive to specify the IP address of eth1.

Here's an example configuration snippet:

```html
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://backend_server;
    proxy_bind 192.168.1.2;
  }
}
```

In this example, Nginx will bind to the IP address 192.168.1.2 on the outgoing connection when making requests to the backend_server defined in the proxy_pass directive.

In summary, the proxy_bind directive is used to specify the local IP address and/or port that Nginx should use when making requests to a backend server using the proxy_pass directive. It's particularly useful when you have multiple network interfaces or IP addresses on your Nginx server.